# JavaScript array To List through a primary way

Tags: javascript

sorry, it's me again, I’d like to create a function whose name is “arrayToList”, however, I don’t know why it doesn’t work , and keeps showing “Unexpected token if”, can anyone help me?

Results I want is

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

However, it keeps showing “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if (line 9)”

```
function arrayToList(arrayx){
  for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length;i++)
    var list={
      value: array[i],
      rest: {
      value: array[i+1],
        rest: null
      }
    };
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You have asked this yesterday

Comment: The posted snippet doesn't trigger the said error. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not to be annoying, but i still wanna use my way to kick this exercise out.

Comment: What is the output supposed to be when the input is [10, 20, 30]?

Comment: Really? But i have already pasted the complete code up here, but they still don't work for me...

Comment: @Thijs let me try!

Comment: @Thijs It still don't work

Comment: I haven't made any changes. I just want to know what the method is supposed to do and your one example doesn't make it clear (at least not for me).

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "through a primary way".

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'd do it:

```js
const arrayToList = a => a.reduceRight((rest, value) => ({value, rest}), null);

const result = arrayToList([10,20,30]);

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want to use higher order functions then here's how to do it:

```js
function arrayToList(a) {
    var length = a.length, result = null;

    while (length > 0) result = { value: a[--length], rest: result };

    return result;
}

var result = arrayToList([10,20,30]);

console.log(result);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, is there any other basic-level way like my codes to fix this?

Comment: Updated my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: So there is no other way to fix this problem from my codes?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're looping over the array from left to right. You need to loop over the array from right to left.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix your code"? If you mean that it should produce the output you want it to do then I already showed you how to do that. If you have some other requirement then I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Wait, why should i loop over my codes from right to left? cause i mean array is like this[10,20,30], and the small numbers start from left!?

Comment: It's because a list is a right recursive data structure. That is to say, `[10,20,30]` becomes `{value:10, rest:{value:20, rest:{value:30, rest:null}}`. Notice that the outermost value (i.e. `10`) is the leftmost value while the innermost value (i.e. `30`) is rightmost value. Data structures are always built from the inside out. Hence, you need to build the innermost list before the outermost one. This means that you have to loop over the array from right to left because the innermost value is the rightmost value. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Big thx, i fully understand what i did wrong in my code, cause i always thought i should run the outermost value first, but now i think i might have to make greats changes, thx again!

Comment: Sorry, may i ask you what "a[--length]" this means?

Comment: [Read the friendly manual.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to solve this

```js
function toList(arr, idx){
    if(idx == arr.length){
        return null
    }
    else {
        return {
            value : arr[idx],
            rest : toList(arr, idx+1)
        }
    }
}

let list = toList([10, 20], 0);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: This is wrong because `toList([], 0)` doesn't return `null`.

Comment: I took the liberty to correct your code.

Comment: yes thanks @AaditMShah, that was the base case

Comment: @A.Kao if your question is answered, then close the question by accepting any of the answers

Answer (score 0):

```
    function arrayToList(arrayx){
      for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length;i++) // for expected output use Math.max.apply(Math, arrayx) instead of arrayx.length;
        { // start braces missing in your code
          var list={
          value: arrayx[i], // corrected this
          rest: {
          value: arrayx[i+1], //corrected this
           rest: null
          }
        };
return list;
        } // end braces missing in your code

    }
```

Comment: It shows"{value: 20, rest: {value: undefined, rest: null}}", not the way i want, sorry

Comment: no need of bracket, if its one line, right?

Comment: can you add what you expect in the question ?

Comment: Not exactly, i want my codes to show like this"{value: 10, rest: { value:20, rest: null}}"

Comment: edited my code..

Answer (score 0):

//Try This

```
function arrayToList(arrayx){
  for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length;i++)
  {
    var list={
      value: array[i],
      rest: {
      value: array[i+1],
        rest: null
      }
    };
  }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: What changes you did??

Comment: Put for loop contents inside {}

Comment: It shows" {value: 20, rest: {value: undefined, rest: null}}", but not the way i want

Comment: check with a snippet, and there is only one line so no need of bracket also.

Answer (score 0):

Array length-1 will work as u wish Try. But it is not at all the way. But You are forcing us making your code work. so done. it will work if there is only two element in array.

```
function arrayToList(arrayx){
      for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length-1;i++) // length-1 should work fine;
        { // start braces missing in your code
          var list={
          value: arrayx[i], // corrected this
          rest: {
          value: arrayx[i+1], //corrected this
           rest: null
          }
        };
        } // end braces missing in your code
        return list;
    }
```